# Picture doesn't show up while my python socket script trying to streaming a picture

Tags: python, sockets

```
import PIL
import ImageGrab
import socket
import io
import atexit


def server():
    while True:
        print('wait..')
        conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
        if conn:
            print(conn)
            print(addr)
            connection = conn.makefile('wb')
            break
    print('connecting..')
    try:
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        ImageGrab.grab().save('1.jpg','JPEG')
        stream.write(io.FileIO('1.jpg','r').readall())
        stream.seek(0)
        connection.write(stream.read())
        stream.seek(0)
        stream.truncate()
    finally:
        print('close connection...')
        connection.close()

def onExit():
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
    print('exit')

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0',8000))
server_socket.listen(0)
server_socket.setblocking(1)

while True:
    server()
```

I'm using this python script to send a real-time screenshot of my pc so that i can check the screenshot on my phone. But somehow the picture doesn't show up or sometimes only a little part of picture is showed..

Thank you for the help >.<